# Switching scenes with a-link causes browser VR mode to drop

Tags: aframe

My project currently has two scenes, one is `index.html` and one is stored in `tour.html`. I'm linking between the two using `a-link` like so:

```
<a-link 
  href="./scenes/tour" 
  title="Office Tour" 
  position="9 2 -5" 
  rotation="0 -40 0"
  image="#officeTourThumbnail"
  >
</a-link>
```

The problem I'm having is that when a user clicks on my `a-link` it drops them out of the browsers virtual reality mode. What is the correct way to link two scenes together that doesn't cause route change?

I'm using Google Chrome for Android with a Google Cardboard.

Comment: On what browsers did you test it ?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski This is on Google Chrome for Android, version `73.0.3683.90`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible today with exceptions. There’s a [proposal to bring immersive navigation to the WebXR standard](https://github.com/immersive-web/navigation) that only ships experimentally on the Oculus Browser for Quest headsets.
In-VR navigation was also part of the old WebVR standard and still available on Firefox desktop for Windows.

Comment: Does the Firefox mobile app behave the same? Or is there a workaround to pseudo link scenes together similar to the image gallery example on the aframe website?

Comment: There’s no workaround. It’s a browser constrain. No link traversal in cardboard devices where there’s no WebVR and the fullscreen API is used as a fallback